# omitting summary statistics from -tabstat- by subgroup if they are missing values

Tags: latex, stata

I am writing a code to export a summary statistics table in Latex by using `tabstat, by()` and `esttab`.

Here you have a toy example that replicates the structure of my data:

```
cls
clear all
set more off

use auto, clear

// Create two groups to be used in the -by()- option
gen rep2="First dataset" if rep78>=3
replace rep2="Second dataset" if rep78<3 

// Recode "price" as completely missing in the first group
replace price=. if rep2=="First dataset"  

// Table
eststo: estpost tabstat weight price mpg trunk, ///
    column(statistics) statistics(count mean median sd) by(rep2) nototal

local sum_statistics "count(label(Observations)) mean(label(Mean) fmt(2)) p50(label(Median)) sd(label(Standard deviation) fmt(2))"

esttab using "table1.tex", replace type ///
    title("Summary Statistics")  ///
    cells("`sum_statistics'") ///   
    noobs nonum booktabs
```

The output displays summary statistics into two subtables, one for each dataset (as defined by `rep2`). These two datasets don't necessarily have the same variables: `price` is completely missing from the first dataset.

I would like to entirely omit the row of summary statistics of `price` for "First dataset" only (leaving it for "Second dataset"). 
This because since the variable `price` is missing for "First dataset", all its summary statistics are missing values. 
This is equivalent to omit the entire row of summary statistics in case "Observations" is equal to 0 in the specific by-group.

I looked into the documentation of `tabstat` but I am not quite sure about how to proceed. Do I have to use the `drop()` option of `estout`?

Many thanks, S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention, you can use the `drop()` option:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto, clear

// Create two groups to be used in the -by()- option
gen rep2="First" if rep78>=3
replace rep2="Second" if rep78<3 

// Recode "price" as completely missing in the first group
replace price=. if rep2=="First dataset"  

// Table
eststo: estpost tabstat weight price mpg trunk, ///
    column(statistics) statistics(count mean median sd) by(rep2) nototal

local sum_statistics "count(label(Observations)) mean(label(Mean) fmt(2)) p50(label(Median)) sd(label(Standard deviation) fmt(2))"

esttab, replace type ///
    title("Summary Statistics")  ///
    cells("`sum_statistics'") ///   
    noobs nonum booktabs drop(First:price)
```

This involves using the *full name* and not just the variable name.

Notice I took out the blank space in the values of the grouping variable. That seems to be troublesome when calling `esttab`, but I leave that to you to explore.

Comment: The variable name is not a big deal, thanks so much for the help!